# Jquery click event of accordion content

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

Inside my accordion content i have rows of data that are loaded by ajax call. I want to capture click of each of these rows separately and get the id from clicked row.
I am able to capture event of click of accordion content. but i am not able to get it separately for each row.

```
<dl id="accRegion">
<#list abc as xyz>          
<dt id="${xyz}"><a class="red">${xyz}</a></dt>
<dd id="${xyz}">
    <dl id="dateList" class="Heading">
    <#list somelist as element>
        <dt id="dateDiv"><a id="${element}" class="orange">${element}</a></dt>                  
    </#list>
    </dl>
</dd>
</#list>
```

this works

```
$("#accRegion dd").click(function(){});
```

but if i try something like below it doesnt work

```
$("#accRegion dd dt").click(function(){});
```

I am not sure whats wrong with this. Appreciate any pointers on this.

Comment: To re-iterate my question, on click of each dateDiv I want to capture value of ${xyz} and ${element}. if I use $("#accRegion dd").click(function(){}) I am able to capture ${xyz} correctly but ${element} comes as first one in the list. And if i use $("#accRegion dd dt").live('click', function() {}) I am able to capture ${element} but ${xyz} always comes as the first element in the list. Any pointers would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As rows are created dynamically, I guess that you should use this:

```
$("#accRegion dd dt").live('click', function() {
  // your code here
});
```

Comment: Yes, this works perfectly. But I have one more problem now. in the ajax call i want to send the id of clicked element. and $(this).find("a").attr("id") gets the id of first row. how to fetch id of clicked row ?

Comment: if this answer is relevant to your question you should accept this answer by clicking in tick left to answer.

Comment: Yes i did that but people stopped responding to my problem after that. so removed that :O. do people only respond to new posts?

Answer (score 0):

You're closing your `<dt>` with a `</div>`

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).on('click',"#ur_id/class", function() {
  // your code here
});
```